# Convert 24 hour Clock to 12 hour clock and add 6 hours

Tags: vba, excel, date, datetime, time

I have infinite rows with with a single column assigned to define date and time in the following 'General Format' "2016.08.10 06:00:00.066". I am aware that you can't convert every single cell in this column "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.000 AM/PM". Therefore I would a single column assigned to "mm/dd/yyyy" and another column assigned to "hh:mm:ss.000 AM/PM". The time is currently 6 hours behind as well so I would like to add 6 hours to it.
I am struggling with this as although the cells are in general or text format the time and date is being displayed as "yyyy.mm.dd hh:mm:ss.000". And can't find a way to split the two in this format
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

To convert the text to a format that Excel will change to a data/time use this:

```
=--SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","/",1),".","/",1)
```

Then to add 6 hours you would use:

```
+ TIME(6,0,0)
```

So to get the date/time is:

```
=--SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","/",1),".","/",1) + TIME(6,0,0)
```

Then simply format the new cell:

```
mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.000 AM/PM
```

---

You can also split it into the date and time:

Date:

```
=INT(--SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","/",1),".","/",1) + TIME(6,0,0))
```

And format it `mm/dd/yyyy`

Time:

```
=MOD(--SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","/",1),".","/",1) + TIME(6,0,0)),1)
```

And format it `hh:mm:ss.000 AM/PM`

[image]

Comment: This is resulting in #VALUE! Is this due to the 'General' cell formatting?

Answer (score 0):

use text: =concatenate(text(a1,"MM"),text(a1,"DD"),text(a1,"YYYY") do the same for the other column  =concatenate(text(a1,"HH"),text(a1,"MM"),text(a1,"SS")

Comment: =CONCATENATE(TEXT(A946,"MM"),TEXT(A946,"DD"),TEXT(A946,"YYYY"))
Results:  2016.10.09 20:03:53.441 2016.10.09 20:03:53.441 2016.10.09 20:03:53.441
Similarly: =CONCATENATE(TEXT(A946,"HH"),TEXT(A946,"MM"),TEXT(A946,"SS"))
Results:  2016.10.09 20:03:53.441 2016.10.09 20:03:53.441 2016.10.09 20:03:53.441

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty strange that you Excel will round off the milliseconds if you try and use a Date-Time format.

```
Enum DTValues
    ReturnDate
    ReturnTime
    ReturnDateTime
End Enum

Function getDateTime(yyyymmdd_hh_mm_ss_000 As String, ReturnValue As DTValues) As Single
    Dim arr
    Dim mSecs As Single
    yyyymmdd_hh_mm_ss_000 = Replace(yyyymmdd_hh_mm_ss_000, " ", ".")
    yyyymmdd_hh_mm_ss_000 = Replace(yyyymmdd_hh_mm_ss_000, ":", ".")

    arr = Split(yyyymmdd_hh_mm_ss_000, ".")
    mSecs = arr(6) / 24 / 60 / 60 / 100

    Select Case ReturnValue
    Case ReturnDate
        getDateTime = CSng(DateSerial(arr(0), arr(1), arr(2)))
    Case ReturnTime
        getDateTime = CSng(TimeSerial(arr(3), arr(4), arr(5))) + mSecs
    Case ReturnDateTime
        getDateTime = CSng(DateSerial(arr(0), arr(1), arr(2))) + CSng(TimeSerial(arr(3), arr(4), arr(5))) + mSecs
    End Select
End Function

Sub ProcessDates()
    Const WORKSHEET_NAME = "Sheet1"
    Const FIRST_ROW = 2
    Const SOURE_COLUMN = 1
    Const DATE_COLUMN = 2
    Const TIME_COLUMN = 3

    Dim Target As Range
    Dim arDate, arTime
    Dim y As Long

    With Worksheets(WORKSHEET_NAME)
        Set Target = .Range(.Cells(FIRST_ROW, SOURE_COLUMN), .Cells(Rows.Count, SOURE_COLUMN).End(xlUp))
    End With
    arDate = Target.Value
    arTime = Target.Value

    For y = 1 To UBound(arDate)
        arDate(y) = getDateTime(arDate(y), ReturnDate)
        arTime(y) = getDateTime(arTime(y), ReturnTime)
    Next

    Target.EntireRow.Columns(DATE_COLUMN).Value = arDate
    Target.EntireRow.Columns(TIME_COLUMN).Value = arTime

End Sub
```

Comment: I am receiving a compile error: user-defined type not defined

Comment: Do you have the Enumeration at the top of the module?

Comment: Yes, as I need the worksheet to perform other tasks as well